# Getting an Unexpected token after Objective-C string error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, forward-declaration, build-error

I have a class called Caching.h. The below 3 lines of code are given below

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@class ODataEntry;
@class ODataFeed;
```

I get the error "Unexpected token after  Objective-C string at the line

```
@class ODataEntry
```

[image]

I have added the ODataEntry.h file to the header search path of the project. Is there anything else that must be done for the @Class forward declaration?

Comment: Can you post the source of ODataEntry.m? It sounds like something is awry in there.

Comment: Sorry I cannot do that. As all that is accessible to me from this project is an OData.h file and a library that contains the implementation of this.

Comment: The error is probably in Caching.m or some other .m file that imports Caching.h.

Comment: @MartinR: That was the what fixed the problem. Then was a ; missing in a constant that imported Caching.h.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 4):

Problems elsewhere can cause unexpected errors...

Try checking other files for errors and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: In my case it was a missing `;` in another class... But this silly compiler didn't want to tell it to me...